# Go install error: ambiguous import: found github.com/hashicorp/consul/api in multiple modules

Tags: go, go-get, goinstall

I'm trying to install Levant but I'm getting the error:

```
go install github.com/hashicorp/levant
build github.com/hashicorp/levant: cannot load github.com/hashicorp/consul/api: ambiguous import: found github.com/hashicorp/consul/api in multiple modules:
    github.com/hashicorp/consul v0.0.0-20171026175957-610f3c86a089 (/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/consul@v0.0.0-20171026175957-610f3c86a089/api)
    github.com/hashicorp/consul/api v1.15.2 (/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/consul/api@v1.15.2)
```

I tried installing one version module separately:

```
go get github.com/hashicorp/consul/api@v1.15.2
```

Also:

```
go mod download /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/consul@v0.0.0-20171026175957-610f3c86a089/api
/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/consul@v0.0.0-20171026175957-610f3c86a089/api: malformed module path "/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/consul": empty path element
```

What do I need to install Levant without errors?

**upd:** I was able to install Levant by downloading the binaries, but I couldn't fix the error with go get/install:
download binaries https://releases.hashicorp.com/levant/ and run unzip

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
go install github.com/hashicorp/levant@latest
```

See [Compile and install packages and dependencies](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies):

> If the arguments have version suffixes (like @latest or @v1.0.0), "go install" builds packages in module-aware mode, **ignoring the go.mod file in the current directory or any parent directory, if there is one**. This is useful for installing executables without affecting the dependencies of the main module.
>
> ...
>
> If the arguments don't have version suffixes, "go install" may run in module-aware mode or GOPATH mode, depending on the GO111MODULE environment variable and the presence of a go.mod file. See 'go help modules' for details. **If module-aware mode is enabled, "go install" runs in the context of the main module**.

BTW, the error message indicates that your main module (the current directory or any parent directory that contains a `go.mod` file) depends on a very old module `github.com/hashicorp/consul@v0.0.0-20171026175957-610f3c86a089`. A `go.mod` file is added to https://github.com/hashicorp/consul in 2019 (see [this commit](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/commit/47c390025b77450cde9ad4cbc47d63b55caeda79)). You should upgrade this dependency for the main module. But if your purpose is to install the `levant` tool, you can ignore this issue now.